# Adding sentence starter words into the dictionary

Tags: python

I have some text and I have got a task in Python with a reading module: "Find the dictionary of words that are sentence starters.

In other words, if a word is at the beginning of a sentence include it in the dictionary." The file is .txt and it contains around 10-15 paragraphs.

Do you have ideas about how it can be improved?

```
f = open("1.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
words = [line.split(maxsplit=1)[0] for line in f if line.strip()]
for line in f:
    if line.strip():
        words.append(line.split(maxsplit=1)[0])
print(words)
```

[Full Text](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/scyXBwzW8t/)

Comment: What typically comes right before a sentence-starter word?

Comment: Can you share the example of your dataset?

Comment: @CharlesDupont a dot and white space " ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each sentence will end with a period, so the text can be split at `.` characters to get each sentence. Also, use the `strip()` method to get rid of white space.

Then, I think it's easier to use a regular expression to get the first word of each sentence in `sentences`. The `[A-Za-z']+` can do just this (letters, capital and lowercase, and apostrophes). Get each match by using the `.search()` method, and get the text corresponding to each successful match using the `group()` method.

```py
import re

text = """..."""

regex = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z']+")
sentences = [s.strip() for s in text.split(".")]
matches = [regex.search(s) for s in sentences]
first_words = [m.group() for m in matches if m]
```

I ran this in the shell, and using the text provided in the comments of the original post, the following output is below:

```py
>>> first_words
['The', 'Woodhouse', 'Knightleys', 'The', 'As', 'The']
```

---

*Edit 1*

For reading from a file:

```py
import re

with open("1.txt") as file:
    text = file.read()

regex = re.compile(r"[A-Za-z']+")
sentences = [s.strip() for s in text.split(".")]
matches = [regex.search(s) for s in sentences]
first_words = [m.group() for m in matches if m]
```

Comment: I tried your Edit 1 code and the output contains no error but at the same time it's blank. [This is a screenshot of the code on visual studio code.](https://prnt.sc/12v08j7)

Comment: @YemlihaKıyakoğlu You probably just need to print the output. So add the line `print(first_words)` to the end of your code.

Comment: It's a newbie mistake :D, thanks for your patience. The code is working perfectly.

Comment: @YemlihaKıyakoğlu No worries! I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

### This code assumes you don't use space after a period (.)

```
text= "This is the text of nothing.Just being the text of nothing.It is something about nothing."

def starters(sentence):
    on_start=False
    current=""
    last=[]
    for dot in sentence:
        if dot==".":
            on_start=True
        if on_start:
            current+=dot
        if dot==" " and current!="":
            on_start=False
            last.append(current[1:])
            current=""
    return last


print(starters(text))
```

Output:
`['Just ', 'It ']`

### This code assumes you use a space after a period

```
text= "This is the text of nothing. Just being the text of nothing. It is something about nothing. A letter for testing one letter"

def starters(sentence):
    on_start=False
    current=""
    last=[]
    for dot in sentence:
        if dot==".":
            on_start=True
        if on_start:
            current+=dot
        if dot==" " and len(current)>2:
            on_start=False
            last.append(current[1:])
            current=""
    return last


print(starters(text))
```

Output:

```
[' Just ', ' It ', ' A ']
```

For getting the first word too, we need to set `on_start=True` and `current=sentence[0]`.

Comment: But what about `"This"`? According to OP's definition, `"This"` should also be a sentence starter.

Comment: How can I make it work with space after a dot? and yes what about "This"?

Comment: @JacobLee to do so```on_start=True``` and ```current=sentence[0]```.

Comment: @YemlihaKıyakoğlu I've edited code for both, with space and without space.

Comment: I appreciate for both but both of the codes give me an output= "[]" I changed the first line to define my text `file = "text= open("emma.txt")` could it be the problem? and here is my [full text](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/scyXBwzW8t/)